# How to synchronize product stock data between different databases in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I´m working on a joomla website (Virtuemart 2.0.6 webshop) and the plan is to make 2 or maybe even 3 seperate webshops with different domain names and databases but the owner uses the same warehouse for all the shops.

So I´m searching to find a way to syncronize the product stock in multiple Virtuemart shops.

Basically I´m looking for way to only share one specific table field between the shops.
Specifically in Virtuemart 2.xx the product stock data is stored in the table:
"jos_virtuemart_products"
field name: "product_in_stock"

I have looked everywhere for the answer to this one, but I haven´t found anything I could use to solve this problem.

Comment: I just want to clarify that all the shops will have the same product inventory but the product names, descriptions and prices will be different in each shop.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to code a custom plugin to do this if you want to have different product names, descriptions, and prices. In any case, it is going to take a custom plugin to achieve your synchronization.

Probably the best way to do it is write a plugin that updates the other sites when an order is completed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer.
This does indeed seem like the only solution.
I haven´t had any explerience coding plugins to Virtuemart before, so I really don´t know where to begin in that regard. Would it be a huge task to make such a plugin for a noob like myself?

Comment: It really depends on how familiar you are with PHP and Joomla/VM plugins. Take a look at the documentation. If this makes sense to you, then you should have no problem.

https://dev.virtuemart.net/projects/1/wiki/Plugin_system
http://dev.virtuemart.net/projects/1/wiki/Developing_a_module_or_plugin_for_Virtuemart_2